# My zodiac sign is: [REDACTED]

Tags: knowledge, steganography, outer-space

The answer is my zodiac sign.

> κπτυχ |
> εηδμθ |
> βαγδι |
> γδεζθ |
> αβγδε+1 |
> βθ40pε |
> δεζφλ

> The answer to this is a sun, but that sun is inside the my constellation's zodiac sign.

Comment: Among only 12 possibilities due to redundancy my first guess would be Scorpius and Antares.

Comment: You are correct- you can click the answer box and answer.

Answer (score 2):

Scorpius and Antares

> Just associative indices: REDACTED is 8 letter word to hide constellation and there are 7 groups of greek letters for the name of the sun (star).

> REDacted associates to the colour of the star

> There are not so much bright stars with commonly known names within zodiac, and only a few candidates of red colour, Aldebaran has 8 letters, Antares 7 letters. Choosing Scorpius instead of Scorpio achieves 8 letters for constellation.

Comment: Well- you are correct but not right in a way,,,,